# Load data of a CSV file into a DB2 table with a SQL command

Tags: csv, insert, db2

I first used this sql to make a script that inserted CSV file data into my MariaDB table:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Driver:/DBCsvFiles/my_table.csv'
    INTO TABLE my_database_name.my_table
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

I now need to do the same for a DB2 database but I don't know how. I did some checks and did find something like this here [IMPORT script on IBM DB2 Cloud using RUN SQL Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57684865/import-script-on-ibm-db2-cloud-using-run-sql-interface/57685690#57685690):

```
INSERT INTO my_database_name.my_table
    SELECT * 
    FROM EXTERNAL 'Driver:/DBCsvFiles/my_table.csv' 
    USING (DELIMITER ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS REMOTESOURCE YES)
```

But I can't get it to work. I Think most of the answers I find are through the DB2 Command Window and not through a SQL command. I'm still stuck on the needed syntax and this error that I get when I run the SQL in DBeaver:

> Token SQL Error [42601]: [SQL0104] 'Driver:/DBCsvFiles/my_table.csv' is invalid. Valid tokens: FOR USE
> SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH LIMIT.

Comment: You need to provide more info in order to get help. Why does DB2 think your file is a token? Where is the link that gave you the structure.  Any more info is useful.

Comment: @TobyAllen Thanks for the reply, I did add some more information mabey it helps?

Comment: What is your db2-SERVER platform (z/os, i series, linux/unix/windows/cloud) ?  If your SERVER platform is linux/unix/windows/cloud, you can only use EXTERNAL TABLES if the VERSION of the Db2-server supports that feature, (What is your Db2-server VERSION? ) , but you can use the ADMIN_CMD stored procedure to run the IMPORT or LOAD commands (note: they are commands, not sql) as long as the CSV file is *addressable* FROM the Db2-server (either local to the Db2-server, or on a network drive that is accessible to the Db2-instance-owner account).   READ THe DOCS.

Comment: Db2 has LOAD and IMPORT commands / utilities. As others said, provide more information. And all Db2 versions have publicly available online help